# how to change background image of an activity

Tags: android-layout, android-activity

Hei every one.
I'm an starter android programmer and I'd like know how can I make a custom them.for example how can I set an image for background of an activity.

Answer (score 0):

place an image file in the `drawable` folder of your android project,then in your activity's xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/myId"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:background="@drawable/backgroundImage">   <!--specify the image here-->
</RelativeLayout>
```